# Getting Cross Origin when trying to add g-reCaptcha in angular

Tags: angularjs, recaptcha

I am getting this error.

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:9001' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 405.
```

Answer (score -1):

This is an extra security step for the server to ensure requests coming from clients are legitimate. Otherwise a client could fake a response and the server would be blindly trusting that the client is a verified human.

Use following google chrome extension:

[Google chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en)